# How to insert into mysql table from bash with quotes in values?

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

I obtain the result of a bash file process into a variable.
The variable content should be inserted into a mysql table from bash cmd:

```
content="File '/test.csv' was imported"

mysql --user=root --password=rootpw --database=$DB
    -e "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, '$content')"
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
       to use near '' was imported' at line 1
```

Question: how can I deal with single quotes contained in a variable, when inserting to mysql?

I tried all variants of `$content`, `'$content'` and `"$content"`, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal quotes need to be doubled. Try

```bash
mysql --user=root --password=rootpw --database=$DB
    -e "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, '${content//\'/\'\'}')"
```